# Apex Set: How to iterate through a set when you don't know it's data type?

Tags: apex

Set's cannot be casted to a Set of objects like a list. So if you have a method that can take any object like:

```
public void handler(Object any_var_including_a_set)
```

Is there a way to dynamically iterate over the Set's contents without knowing the data type that the set is holding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no notion of `Object.getClass()` in Apex; the alternative is using `instanceof` with a known set of types.

Below is modified `handler` that uses `JSON.serialize`, then determines whether `ofAnyType` is an array, object, or some other primitive.

Assuming an array (either a `Set` or `List` in Apex), it can be cast to `List<Object>`. This can be iterated over to determine the `instanceof` for each member.

An alternative implementation would use `ofAnyType instanceof Set<Object_Type_Here>`, though is not as abstract.

```
public static void handler(Object ofAnyType)
{       
    String jsonString = JSON.serialize(ofAnyType);
    System.debug(jsonString);

    // if array, use List<Object>
    if(jsonString.length() > 0 && jsonString.startsWith('[') && jsonString.endsWith(']'))
    {
        List<Object> mapped = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

        // iterate over mapped, check type of each Object o within iteration
        for(Object o : mapped)
        {
            if(o instanceof String)
            {
                System.debug((String)o);
            }
        }
    }

    // if object, use Map<String, Object>
    else if(jsonString.length() > 0 && jsonString.startsWith('{') && jsonString.endsWith('}'))
    {
        Map<String, Object> mapped = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

        // iterate over mapped, check type of each Object o within iteration
        for(Object o : mapped.values())
        {
            if(o instanceof String)
            {
                System.debug((String)o);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For quick testing, I saved `handler` in my `StackTesting` class. You may use the code below to execute anonymous Apex and see the results.

```
Integer i = 42;
Set<String> strs = new Set<String>{'hello', 'world'};
Set<Object> objs = new Set<Object>{'hello', 2, new Account(Name = 'Sure')};

StackTesting.handler(i);
StackTesting.handler(strs);
StackTesting.handler(objs);
```

Note that a more robust implementation would make use of `Pattern` within Apex, which would take place of the `.startsWith` and `.endsWith` for determining whether `jsonString` is an array or object.

Comment: thanks roger! such an interesting work around and it's exactly what i was looking for.